# Why can I only have 1 active texture in my fragment shader?

Tags: c++, opengl

I tried writing an application of OpenGL that renders a triangle where each vertex has an index to its texture specified by its vertex array data. The actual texture to be rendered will be bound to an active texture unit in the fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;

flat in uint frag_texture_index;
in vec2 frag_texture_coords;

uniform sampler2D textures[3];

void main() {
  if (frag_texture_index == 0u) {
    // Purple.
    out_color = texture(textures[0], frag_texture_coords);
  } else if (frag_texture_index == 1u) {
    // Blue.
    out_color = texture(textures[1], frag_texture_coords);
  } else if (frag_texture_index == 2u) {
    // Yellow.
    out_color = texture(textures[2], frag_texture_coords);
  }
}
```

I set up the vertex data like so:

```
// Index of each texture in the fragment shader.
enum Color {
  Purple = 0,
  Blue = 1,
  Yellow = 2,
};

// Structure for each vertex.
struct vert_struct {
  float x, y;
  Color texture_index;
};

// The triangle vertex data.
vert_struct triangle_vertices[] = {
  // x     y    tid                                                                                                                                         
  { 0.0,  0.5,  Yellow },
  { 0.5, -0.5,  Yellow },
  {-0.5, -0.5,  Yellow },
};

// Vertex indices.
GLuint triangle_indices[] = {0, 1, 2};

// Instantiate triangle element.                                                                                                                          
GLuint triangle_element_buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &triangle_element_buffer);
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, array_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_vertices), triangle_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangle_element_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_indices), triangle_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vert_struct), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(vert_struct, x)));
glVertexAttribIPointer(1, 1, GL_INT, sizeof(vert_struct), reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(vert_struct, texture_index)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I set up the 3 textures like so:

```
// Create textures.                                                                                                                                         
GLuint textures[3];
glGenTextures(3, textures);

GLuint* p;
GLuint purple[256 * 256];
GLuint blue[256 * 256];
GLuint yellow[256 * 256];
p = purple;
while (p - purple != 256 * 256) *p++ = 0xffff00ffu;
p = blue;
while (p - blue != 256 * 256) *p++ = 0xffff0000u;
p = yellow;
while (p - yellow != 256 * 256) *p++ = 0xff00ffffu;

// Purple.                                                                                                                                                  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[Purple]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, purple);

// Blue.                                                                                                                                                    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[Blue]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, blue);

// Yellow.                                                                                                                                                  
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[Yellow]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, yellow);
```

And draw:

```
// Clear screen.                                                                                                                                            
glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 720);
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Use the triangle program.                                                                                                                                
glUseProgram(triangle_program);

// Bind textures to each unit.                                                                                                                              
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);
  glUniform1ui(uniform_locations.textures[i], i);
}

// Draw triangle.                                                                                                                                           
glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, reinterpret_cast<void*>(0));
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in uint texture_index;

flat out uint frag_texture_index;
out vec2 frag_texture_coords;

void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
  // Forward texture index and coordinates to fragment shader.                                                                                              
  frag_texture_index = texture_index;
  frag_texture_coords = (position + vec2(1, 1)) / 2.;
}
```

Because I gave each `texture_index` component of my vertex array a value of `Yellow`, or enum value 2, and the texture filled with yellow texels is bound to GL_TEXTURE2, I expected to see a yellow triangle rendered in my window. But instead, it's purple. I have debugged everything I can think of and was able to confirm that the vertex data is making its way to the fragment shader. In fact, if I manually apply the color to the output of my fragment shader, it works:

```
...
  } else if (frag_texture_index == 2u) {
    // Yellow.
    //out_color = texture(textures[2], frag_texture_coords);
    out_color = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
  }
...
```

But unfortunately, the shader just does not want to sample the texture that is bound to the unit indicated by the `textures` uniform element. In fact, it seems that the only texture it will ever sample is the texture bound to GL_TEXTURE0. If I manually bind the yellow texture to that texture unit, I get a yellow triangle, and, likewise, the triangle will always be yellow regardless of the value of each vertex's `texture_index`. So what is going on here? Why does my fragment shader ignore the other texture units and how do I get a `textures` uniform that can reference more than one texture?

In case anyone was wondering, here is how I got the `textures` uniform locations:

```
// Get uniform locations.                                                                                                                                 
struct {                                                                                                                                                  
  GLint textures[3];                                                                                                                                      
} uniform_locations;                                                                                                                                      
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {                                                                                                                             
  uniform_locations.textures[i] = glGetUniformLocation(triangle_program, ("textures[" + std::to_string(i) + "]").c_str());                                
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether compilation of the shaders and subsequent binding of the program is successful? I doubt that you can use arrays of `sampler2D` in fragment shaders. Also check the return value of `glGetUniformLocation()`.

Comment: Why don't you use several textures instead of `texture0`, `texture1`, and `texture2`? Or, why don't you use texture array (`GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`)?

Comment: @rpress Yes, I have checked results of compilation and linking and return codes from glGetUniformLocation. I omitted that code for brevity. Everything compiles, links, and locates uniforms fine.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko Using separate variable names for each texture (`texture0`, `texture1`, `texture2`) produces the same results. They all return texels from the texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE0`. I considered using texture arrays, but most documentation on them states they aren't meant for what I ultimately plan on using them for (a collection of textures with different sizes). However, it doesn't seem like the sampler2D array is getting any closer to a viable solution, so I may have to figure out how to make `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` work instead.

Comment: If you have the same issue with separate variable names then something is wrong with the way you assign them. If you work on Windows you could try to use RednerDoc to find out what the cause of the issue

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I don't use Windows. I also cannot identify what I could be doing wrong in the assignment. I'm not doing anything different than the code I've posted. I have even confirmed that I am assigning the correct integer values to the uniforms by changing the type of the textures array in the fragment shader to be an array of `uint`s and then rendering different colors based on the evaluation of `textures[frag_texture_index]`. It is exactly what you would expect, the values `0`, `1`, and `2`. Edit: same for when I set the types for `texture0`, `texture1`, and `texture2` to `uint`s.

Comment: @wild_mouse: Where does this array `uniform_locations.textures[i]` get its values from?

Comment: @NicolBolas That is shown in the last code block of my question.

Comment: Can this question please be reopened? It was marked as a duplicate, but the question asked in the duplicate is not at all the question I pose, and none of the comments or answers to that question address the issue I'm having.

Comment: @wild_mouse Sorry, but this question is duplicate, because `textures[frag_texture_index]` is undefined behavior. `frag_texture_index` is a fragment shader input (not [Dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression)) and the texture sample depends on this input. It doesn't matter if you do `textures[frag_texture_index]` or `if (frag_texture_index==0) {... textures[0]... }`. Even if you don't want to believe it, you can't trick the system like this. Use a `sampler2DArray` instead of an array of `sampler2D`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You've shed some new light on the situation that is not disclosed in your answer, so I wouldn't consider this a duplicate. No need to be passive aggressive here, I'm perfectly willing to believe information once it has been presented to me. Specifically the fact that this is undefined behavior, which explains why it works for the OP of the other question.

Comment: @wild_mouse I thought you were trying to outsmart the system by using an `if` - `else if` - `else` construct where just `textures[frag_texture_index]` could be used. Anyway there are 2 reasons not to use an array of `sampler2D`: 1. The index must be [Dynamically uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression). 2. The number of texture units is limited and you would have to use a separate texture unit for each element. The usual solution is to use a texture atlas or `sampler2DArray`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I didn't think I was outsmarting anything, I thought what I was doing was convention based on that question and other posts where people have suggested using conditions instead of a uniform index. I hadn't found anything suggesting that even that approach was undefined until you stated it. I really appreciate that information! I have been working on an implementation using sampler2DArray and texelFetch.